# How to use aws-sdk inside webworker of Angular 9?

Tags: angular, aws-sdk, web-worker

```
I installed aws-sdk :- npm install aws-sdk
```

**And then imported aws-sdk inside my worker file like this:**

```
app.worker.ts :- import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

**And then tried to console.log inside addEventListener code is here:-**

```
    addEventListener('message', async ({ data }) => {
    console.log(AWS);
}
```

**After doing this i am getting errors as in screenshot:**

[image]

**I also tried to solve this error for that i defined global in polyfills.ts though it's not working**

```
polyfills.ts :- (window as any).global = window;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. What i am trying to achieve is i am trying to upload file from worker using aws-sdk to s3 from my angular project. Thank you guys!

Comment: Are you running with custom webpack configuration?

Comment: I am not using custom webpack configuration. I haven't changed any configuration,  there is default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**It may help for others too so I am giving the solutions how I solved the issue:-**

Web Workers don't have a global `window` object. So to access the global object we can use `self`instead.

**So to solve my problem I followed these steps:**

**Steps :-**

- In the `app.worker.ts`, To use the Type-Script definition files with the global `AWS` object in a front-end project. We have to add reference types at the top of the worker file e.g `/// <reference types="aws-sdk" />`.
- Define window `const window = self;`
- And after the that import aws-sdk scripts `importScripts('assets/js/aws-sdk.js');` then we'll be able to access the `AWS` object inside `addEventListener('message', async ({ data }) => { console.log(window.AWS) });`
- Here i am importing scripts from assets because i had to customized aws-sdk to avoid window not defined error while calling `s3.createMultipartUpload()`
- Here is the link `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nyaupane/customized_aws_sdk/master/assets/js/aws-sdk.js`  of customized aws_sdk in case if your requirement is same as mine otherwise you can customize according as your requirement.
- Final `app.worker.ts` will look like this: `https://github.com/nyaupane/customized_aws_sdk/blob/master/assets/worker/app.worker.ts`

**Now it works perfectly for multipart uploading...using aws_sdk in angular9 web worker.**

Comment: Thanks it really helpful, can you tell me what exactly  you changed in SDK